# Tensorflow Object Detection Training Error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am following tutorial for Tensorflow Object Detection
[link](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)

and getting the following command when i try this command

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

error:

```
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\trainer.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import variables_helper
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\utils\variables_helper.py", line 23, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 42, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import distributions
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\distributions\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.estimator import *
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\distributions\python\ops\estimator.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.head import _compute_weighted_loss
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.experiment import Experiment
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\experiment.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import tpu_estimator
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python import profiler
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\python\profiler\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.profiler.tpu_profiler_analysis_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\profiler\tpu_profiler_analysis_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.profiler import tpu_profiler_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_contrib_dot_tpu_dot_profiler_dot_tpu__profiler__pb2
  File "C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\tpu\profiler\tpu_profiler_pb2.py", line 395, in <module>
    _sym_db.RegisterServiceDescriptor(_TPUPROFILER)
AttributeError: 'SymbolDatabase' object has no attribute 'RegisterServiceDescriptor'
```

anybody faced this types of error? If so how can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I is definitely related to something being off in your setup.py. Here is a thread that may help: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/issues/146. You may need to specify the version of the packages you are using as well.

Comment: it actually didn't solve my problem. actually i follow the tutorial (link is given).

Answer (score 1):

[link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3967)

In here the same issue is discussed and they found  a solution. The problem is protobuf version i think.